# Call WebService in Handler of message sending in Sirikit ios 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10, sirikit

I'm implementing the app extension with `SiriKit` framework, when user say **"Send the message in XYZ app"**, `Siri` will send this message to the intent. After processing the intent, i want to call my `WebService API` to send this message to my own Server. The question is How can i call the WebService API in intent handler, because when calling the Webservice API, i need to do some authentication before sending message. If possible, please give some example code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not know, how to authentication works, But there is user token, and user name. And what is intent ?

Comment: @ArpitBParekh: The intent is the message content user want to send. Do you have any experience on this ?

Comment: No, but if we can get something out of this. If you want to get your answer, keep trying to update/edit your question, so that your answer will be up on the stackoverflow question list.

Comment: intent means message content or user, whom you are sending the message. ?

Comment: @DanielHuynh, Did you find any solution?